# Mockito 5.8.0 is not properly injecting mocks in superclass of Apache Camel Route

Tags: mockito, apache-camel, quarkus

Faced this problem: with updating Quarkus from **3.6.x** to **3.7.x** it started to use Apache Camel **4.3.0** instead of **4.2.0**, which intrinsically uses Mockito **5.8.0** instead of **5.3.1**.
And this causes this kind of issue:

I have a base route in my app:

```java
public class ExceptionRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Inject CustomExceptionMapper exceptionMapper;
  @Inject ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(WebApplicationException.class)
      .id("exceptional-route")
      // processing
  }
}
```

And I have a business route extending the base one:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BusinessRoute extends ExceptionRoute {

 
  private final ServiceA serviceA;
  private final ServiceB serviceB;

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    super.configure();
    // business logic here
  }
}
```

I wrote this test to check the route:

```java
class BusinessRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  @InjectMocks private BusinessRoute businessRoute;
  @Mock private ServiceA serviceA;
  @Mock private ServiceB serviceB;
  @Mock private CustomExceptionMapper customExceptionMapper;
  @Mock private ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    return businessRoute;
  }

  @Test
  // all the tests
}
```

The problem is that with Mockito **5.3.1** all the tests are passing, the mocks are being generated correctly and injected as expected, i.e. I have in my BusinessRoute mocks of ServiceA and ServiceB, and in my ExceptionRoute mocks of CustomExceptionMapper and ObjectMapper.

But with Mockito **5.8.0** in superclass (ExceptionRoute) none of mocks are injected, which causes tests to fail because of NPE.

I tried to use `@QuarkusTest` which starts the whole application context and with some changes in beans scopes I made it work, but I don't want to make it like this, I want to have the unit tests with mocks via Mockito.

I handled this by explicitly defining version of Mockito in `<dependencyManagement>`, but I wanna know what have changed and why it is not working as expected.

Any of you faced the same issue?
How to overcome it with the version **5.8.0** and even more recent (**5.10.0** AFAIK)?